# Prestashop 1.7 custom field

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I have added 'credit_impot' custom field to my prestashop 1.7. It works but I can't update the custom field.

here is my codes

Product.php
public $credit_impot;
...
'fields' => array(
            'credit_impot' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),

\src\PrestaShopBundle\Form\Admin\Product\ProductPrice.php
$builder->add('credit_impot', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType', array(
            'required' => false,
            'attr' => ['placeholder' => $this->translator->trans('Andrana', [], 'Admin.Catalog.Help')]
        ));

\src\PrestaShopBundle\Model\Product\AdminModelAdapter.php
['step2' => ['credit_impot' => $this->product->credit_impot, ...

\src\PrestaShopBundle\Resources\views\Admin\Product\form.html.twig
{{ form_widget(form.step2.credit_impot) }}